# Performing load testing in a Node Application having nginx and load balancer

Tags: node.js, nginx, jmeter, load-testing

I am having a node application which is providing a portal for users to give online exams. Now I want to perform load testing on this server. For that I am using apache Jmeter. On the backend side I have created two node server instances(8gb ram, 4 core each ) and managing them with load balancer with Nginx. So when I am performing load testing with 500 users, I am getting gateway timeout (504) error. Also for some request I am not getting response in Jmeter. At the same time when I am checking my both node server, I see pretty normal usage of cpu and ram. 
so How can I solve this? What might be the cause for the issue ? Should I have to change anything in nginx configuration ?

Is there any issue with my load-testing environment ? Do I required to use anyother way or tool for Load testing ?

Answer (score 0):

504 is Gateway Timeout error which it means it caused by Nginx configuration, according to [solved solution](http://www.codetweet.com/nginx/solved-504-gateway-timeout-error-in-nginx-web-server/) you should increase the following to prevent/reduce such errors

```
client_header_timeout 3000;
client_body_timeout 3000;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
client_max_body_size 32m;
fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
```